# Tensorflow: empty computational graph & garbage collection

Tags: tensorflow

1 EMPTY GRAPH ERROR

Hey I am trying to run multiple tensorflow graphs completely separate and am running into the following inheritance problem.

Also does

```
import tensorflow as tf


class A:

    g = tf.Graph()
    g.as_default()
    s = tf.Session(graph=g)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    __call__ = lambda self,X: self.s.run(self.y, {self.x:X})


class B(A):

    y = 2 * A.x


test = B()
print test([1,1,2])
```

error

```
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()
```

---

2 - GARBAGE COLLECTION

I am also curious to find out about deleting these distinct graphs, if I close the session with Session().close() and it is the only session aware of the graph will this graph now disappear and be garbage collected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Question 1

If you want your operations to be added to a specific graph, you need to use `with g.as_default()` as context:

```py
class A:

    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    s = tf.Session(graph=g)

    __call__ = lambda self,X: self.s.run(self.y, {self.x:X})


class B(A):

    with g.as_default():
        y = 2 * A.x


test = B()
print test([1,1,2])
```

(PS: your code is really badly written, hope it's just for testing)

---

### Question 2

A graph is not affected by a corresponding session.

You can create a graph, open a session and close it, the graph will remain intact:

```py
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    # build graph...
    x = tf.constant(1)

sess = tf.Session(graph=g)
sess.run(x)
sess.close()

# Now we can create a new session with the same graph
sess2 = tf.Session(graph=g)
sess2.run(x)
sess2.close()
```

Comment: You cannot delete a graph or close it. You can just stop using it. If you want to reset the default graph to an empty one, you can use `tf.reset_default_graph()`

Comment: In which situation do you need to build a graph, run it and then delete it? In my opinion TensorFlow is better than Theano and each day becomes even better.

Comment: yea there is a bunch better in tensorflow like compile time, but i am trying to write a pruneable neural net and both TF and theano don't support computational graph pruning... at least TF supports adding

Comment: would you happen to know if persistent unused graph would be a big optimisation problem? like if i chose to run on my gpu, would it's memory be filled with unused but loaded tf.Variables() ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot remove a graph node in TensorFlow. I guess a big graph with lots of unused nodes would be a bit heavy, but it will depend on the size of the whole graph. The question about memory and Variables would be a good one to post in another StackOverflow question, where maybe people from the TF team would answer.